# If parent Dont have Class do something in the child class

Tags: jquery

I try to add class to the child if the parent lost one of the 2 class he already have.

The HTML code is:

```
<span class="f-menu-wrapper">
  <span id="fmenuselector" class="circle"> <!-- Will toggleClass -->
    <span class="default"></span> 
    <span class="content rmclass"> <!--Hiden by defualt controled by .rmclass &  Will toggleClass -->
      Content to be show and hide
    </span> 
  </span>
</span>
```

And I'm using Jquery to control 2 things:

1- `.toggleClass` new class `.circle_opened` to `<span id="fmenuselector" class="circle">`

2- `.toggleClass` `.rmclass` inside `<span class="default rmclass">`

This is my JQuery code to achieve this:

```
$('#fmenuselector > .default').click(function(){
        $('span.circle_opened').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('circle_opened');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('circle_opened');
        $('#fmenuselector > span.content').toggleClass('rmclass');
        if (!$(this).parent().not(".circle_opened")) {
            $('#fmenuselector > span.content').addClass('rmclass');
        }
    });
```

The problem come, when the parent `<span id="fmenuselector" class="circle">` **Dont** have the class `.circle_opened` the `<span class="default">` **Dont** add the class `.rmclass`

can some one explain where is the wrong in my code please?

Thank you ,
Tariq

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you're trying to do?

I've made a jsfiddle with your code ... is it not doing what you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/5kcaqybd/2/

Comment: Thank you for help. I need that, if the class .circle_opened will be removed from the parent a class .rmclass will be added again to the span content

Comment: That is exactly what is happening in your code. Look at the jsfiddle link above. It sounds like it's doing what you're wanting it to do.